# Not able to add fonts to FontProvider using embedded resource

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, itext7

While converting Html to Pdf templates, I am adding fonts to `FontProvider`.
I am trying to load my font files as embedded resources.

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(TestClass).Assembly;
string fPath= assembly.GetName().Name + "." + "Fonts.";
List<string> fD= assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(name => name.StartsWith(fPath)).ToList();
```

But while creating `FonrProgram` using above `fD`, I am getting error.(Error : Document has no pages.) It is not able to load the font file.

```
foreach (string font in fD)
{
 FontProgram fp = FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(font);
 fontProvider.AddFont(fp, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
}
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Note: I am able to load the font file by giving below directory path.

```
string font = @"\SEGOEUI.TTF";
FontProvider fp = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
FontProgram defaultFont = FontProgramFactory.CreateFont(font);
fp.AddFont(defaultFont);
```

Comment: I found the solution for this issue. :)

Comment: What's the solution? @Subham Kumar